# How to migrate HUE 4.2 to HUE 4.4 on EMR cluster

Tags: django, hive, amazon-emr, hue

I'm currently running an EMR 5.17.0 cluster with HUE 4.2, now I'm planning to upgrade my EMR to 5.24 and migrate the HUE from 4.2 to 4.4.

I've followed the instruction from AWS "How to migrate a Hue database from an existing Amazon EMR cluster"

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-migrate-a-hue-database-from-an-existing-amazon-emr-cluster/

But I got below exception when I try to import the hue-mysql.json from my new cluster! seems the schedule not be supported on HUE 4.4, does anyone have any good suggestions on how to fix this?

[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-127 ~]$ sudo /usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue loaddata hue-mysql.json

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 14, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/usr/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 216, in entry
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 109, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 166, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 88, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 82, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 129, in Deserializer
    field = Model._meta.get_field(field_name)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/options.py", line 619, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/hadoop/hue-mysql.json': ContentType has no field named 'name'
```